# OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp

Tags: python, time-series

I'm using GluonTS for a timeseries problem.

```
data = common.ListDataset([{"start": df.index[0],
                            "target": df.price[:"2021-12-01"]}],
                             freq="1M")
```

I'm getting this error in the above line

> 8866-12-31 00:00:00: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 8866-12-31
>   00:00:00

I have checked that the dataframe `df` and it only has timestamps ranging from year 2017 to 2021.

This is what `df.index` looks like:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2017-02-01', '2017-03-01', '2017-04-01', '2017-05-01',
               '2017-06-01', '2017-07-01', '2017-08-01', '2017-09-01',
               '2017-10-01', '2017-11-01',
               ...
               '2020-12-01', '2021-01-01', '2021-02-01', '2021-03-01',
               '2021-04-01', '2021-05-01', '2021-06-01', '2021-07-01',
               '2021-08-01', '2021-09-01'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=82198, freq=None)
```

I don’t understand the error based on my data.

Answer (score 0):

I think `df.index[0]` might be the problem. It seems its `8866`, which will be interpreted as the year. Try providing a timestamp for start, as the documentation states:
"start: start date of the time series"